# React Navigation 5 no header prop? Custom header component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How do you implement a custom header component in React Navigation 5?

There is a variable for header, but assigning a component to it doesn't show anything, do you need to assign headerLeft, headerTitle and headerRight for every screen?

```
        <Stack.Screen name="IndexScreen" component={IndexScreen}
          options={{
            header: () => <HeaderComponent /> 
          }} /> //shows nothing

        <Stack.Screen name="IndexScreen" component={IndexScreen}
          options={{
            headerLeft: () => <HeaderLeftComponent />, 
            headerTitle: () => <HeaderTitleComponent />, 
            headerRight: () => <HeaderRightComponent /> // to much repetition
          }} />
```

Comment: What does your `HeaderComponent` look like, because it's working for me. Creating a snack might also be a good idea, to make it easier to debug.

Comment: @Bas I managed to get a custom component to work as a header and made a snack: https://snack.expo.io/@johanmelin/4c7d80. Now I'm just curious how I can get all the header logic into this component, like headerRight: () => <View>

Comment: Simple creating an object with the settings doesn't work

<Stack.Screen 
          options={{ HeaderSettings }}
        />
const HeaderSettings = {
  header: HeaderComponent
}

Comment: I can get both settings and header component to work, but not both at the same time.
options={{ 
            ...HeaderSettings, 
            header: props => <HeaderComponent {...props} />, 
          }}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`header`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#header) attribute in `screenOptions` prop from `Stack.Navigator` (if it is a common header):

```js
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    header: YourHeader
  }}
>
  // ...
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Or `header` attribute in `options` from `Stack.Screen` for each screen:

```js
<AppStack.Screen
  name='YourScreen'
  component={YourComponent}
  options={{ header: YourHeader }}
/>
```

If your header is not showing up, probably the Screen is rendering something with a higher `zIndex` or `elevation`.

---

The docs says which props the `header` component receives, but you can also check it on the [types file](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/stack/src/types.tsx) (on GitHub), search for `StackHeaderProps`.